# Stationarity of MA models in time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, moving-average

I am aware that MA models are always stationary, however I was wondering if this meant that they are always weakly stationary?

Can a MA model being strongly stationary or are they always only weakly stationary?

Answer (score 3):

We have an MA($q$) process

$$ x_t = \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \dotsb + \theta_q \varepsilon_{t-q}. $$

If the error $\varepsilon$ has a distribution that has an infinite second (or even an infinite first) moment (e.g. a Cauchy distribution), an i.i.d. sequence of errors will not be weakly stationary. An MA($q$) process is just a linear combination of $q$ i.i.d. errors. A linear combination of a process that is *not* weakly stationary will in general *not* be weakly stationary itself. Therefore, an MA process based on *non*-weakly-stationary errors will *not* be weakly stationary. Hence, MA process is *not* weakly stationary in general.

However, an MA($q$) process will be strongly stationary because any $n$-element vector within a sequence generated by an MA($q$) process will have the same joint distribution.

Comment: Could you provide a mathematical proof of your last statement? I do not think it holds in general.

Comment: @mpiktas, I removed the statement as I cannot provide a proof right now (or maybe it does not exist). Would you be able to provide some counterexample where strong stationarity does not hold? That would be very interesting.

Comment: I will try to look it up. The question is whether a set of strong stationary processes is a linear one. I do not recall either the proof or a counterexample for this statement.

Comment: Ok, I've found an exercise in van der Vaart book asking to prove that MA process based on strictly stationary series is strictly stationary.

Comment: @mpiktas, Should I include the statement I had before without the proof, or should I skip it if I cannot supply the proof? (For me it was quite intuitive, so I just had it without the proof, but I appreciate the need for rigor.)

Comment: Well the proof is trivial when you think about it. I mistakenly assumed that you are talking about linear combinations of any stationary processes, instead of linear combinations of lags of the same process. Still looking at that statement I feel that it is not entirely clear. I think it would be simpler just to clarify your example with iid Caucy sequence. The MA process from such a sequence will be strictly stationary, but it is clear that its variance is infinite, prohibiting it to be weakly stationary. Sorry for nitpicking, I've already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Seems like I'm late to the party, but if I'm not mistaken iid errors is sufficient for the MA process to be strictly stationary. It can still be so for non-iid errors. Eg if epsilon is a stationary AR(1) with Gaussian errors, then y should be a strictly stationary ARMA. There are some results for this in chapter 7 of Hamilton.

Comment: @hejseb, I thought perhaps MA process requires i.i.d. errors as otherwise it becomes something else than MA (in your example, it becomes ARMA), but it's a matter of definition which I might have wrong.

Comment: Good point. It's no longer an MA, just looks like one...